# Rails Routing - Posting with same route name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's my routes:

```
root :to                                      => 'sites#index'
match 'sites'                                 => 'sites#index'
match 'sites/:site'                           => 'sites#show'
match 'sites/:site/publish'                   => 'sites#publish', :via => :get
match 'sites/:site/publish'                   => 'sites#push',    :via => :put
match 'sites/:site/:entity_type'              => 'entity#index'
match 'sites/:site/:entity_type/new'          => 'entity#new',    :via => :get
match 'sites/:site/:entity_type/new'          => 'entity#create', :via => :put
match 'sites/:site/:entity_type/:entity_name' => 'entity#edit',   :via => :get
match 'sites/:site/:entity_type/:entity_name' => 'entity#update', :via => :put
```

The problem I'm having is that when I do the POST for the publish routes that it doesn't actually call the action method at all. It states that "entity_type_ parameter (which shouldn't be specified) is set to "publish".

Here's my form:

```
<%= form_tag({:controller => 'sites', :action => 'publish'}) do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'site', params[:site] %>

    <%= submit_tag 'Publish' %>
<% end %>
```

Actually, I needn't specify the hidden field as this is done as a result of the route. When I hit "Publish" this is what happens:

```
Started POST "/sites/kieransenior/publish" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-14 20:35:48 +0100
Processing by EntityController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"bCooYei5XTbfNv4MwXqrYAvBzazdcCZpHr7HufKPcxo=", "site"=>"kieransenior", "commit"=>"Publish", "entity_type"=>"publish"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1ms
```

The HTML form looks like this (for clarity):

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/sites/kieransenior/publish" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="bCooYei5XTbfNv4MwXqrYAvBzazdcCZpHr7HufKPcxo=" /></div>
    <input id="site" name="site" type="hidden" value="kieransenior" />

    <input name="commit" type="submit" value="Publish" />
</form>
```

What am I doing wrong to cause it to POST to the wrong place? It *must* be my routing that's doing it, as the form is correct.

**EDIT**

Controller action for push:

```
def push
   respond_to do |format|
      redirect_to :controller => 'sites', :action => 'show', :site => params[:site]
   end
end
```

Scrap the above, would help if I had my brain screwed on. Looks like I dumped a redirect_to in there at some point and didn't remove the respond_to. Whoops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `match`, you can instead (and you probably should) use `get`, `post`, `put` or whatever verb you plan on using instead of simply saying `match`.

For example, you could do this instead for the two routes you're referring to:

```
get 'sites/:site/publish'     => 'sites#publish'
post 'sites/:site/publish'    => 'sites#push'
```

**EDIT**

It looks like if you're getting a `406` error then your posts are getting rejected because you're not being specific with the format of the submitted content type.

If you use a `respond_to`, normally you specify the content type and what to do for each type -- something like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.xml { render :xml => @people.to_xml }
end
```

In yours, there doesn't seem to be the same format specification:

```
def push
   respond_to do |format|
      redirect_to :controller => 'sites', :action => 'show', :site => params[:site]
   end
end
```

The `406` error usually means you've submitted a content-type to a `respond_to` clause, but don't have that content type specified in the `respond_to` (for example, posted to `/app/model.json` but didn't have a `format.json` clause). In your case, there are *no* format clauses, so this would be why the `406`.

So unless you have a specific reason for using `respond_to`, I'd recommend just removing it for now and leaving:

```
def push
  redirect_to :controller => 'sites', :action => 'show', :site => params[:site]
end
```

Comment: It works using those, which is good, however the redirect doesn't work. The URL stays the same, but the command prompt is stating the following: Started POST "/sites/kieransenior/publish" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-14 20:54:05 +0100
Processing by SitesController#push as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"bCooYei5XTbfNv4MwXqrYAvBzazdcCZpHr7HufKPcxo=", "site"=>"kieransenior", "commit"=>"Publish"}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/sites/kieransenior
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Comment: What's your controller look like for the `push` method? Normally `406` means that your controller is rejecting the post for some reason.

Comment: Edited the original post. In fact, my updates on other forms don't work now as a result of using get/post instead of match.

Comment: Ignore it, I've commented afterwards. Hold on though, got to figure out why my routing isn't working properly yet though.

Comment: Thanks -- Hope this was helpful and helped guide you to the answer for this problem! Best of luck! If this answer got you there, I'd appreciate accepting it.

Comment: For the record, it should've been put as opposed to post. The wrong verb leads to the wrong action it seems in Rails 3.2. Otherwise, this is by far the most detailed response.

Comment: I was wondering -- the original `match` was a `put`, but in your question you wrote `post`.

Answer (score 2):

```
post 'sites/:site/publish'                   => 'sites#publish'
```

Comment: What's with via and match then? I've always thought the way I was doing it was the way it's meant to be done. I've been deceived!